# display text over svg element onmousedown using javascript

Tags: javascript, text, svg, append, appendchild

im trying to display some text on a svg map.
the text should display onmousedown.

here is how i create the svg map

```
<svg id="svg_canvas" width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="map_group">
<title>Layer 1</title>

<rect stroke="#000000" id="bancroft_road" height="449.99998" width="34" y="-0.99998" x="164" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill="#7f7f7f"/>
```

et ecetera for the other elements of the svg map

then i do

```
<script>
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

//import from DOM
var svg = document.getElementById("svg_canvas");
var mileEnd = document.getElementById("mile_end");
```

and add event listeners

```
mileEnd.addEventListener('mousedown', clickedMileEnd, false);
mileEnd.addEventListener('mouseup', unclickedMileEnd,false);
bancroft.addEventListener('mousedown', clickedBancroft, false);
bancroft.addEventListener('mouseup', unclickedBancroft,false);
```

this is where i have problems

```
function showText(target)
{
    var text = document.createElementNS(ns, "text");
    var x = (target.getAttribute('x')).toString;
    text.setAttribute('x',x)
    var y = (target.getAttribute('y')).toString;
    text.setAttribute('y',y);
    var textNode;
    console.log("created textnode");
    if (target.id=="svg_14"||"svg_16")
    {
         textNode = document.createTextNode("People Palace"); 
    }else if (target.id=="svg_11"||"svg_12"||"svg_13")
    {
         textNode = document.createTextNode("Engineering Building"); 
    }
    switch (target.id){
            case "bancroft_road":
                textNode = document.createTextNode("Bancroft Road"); 
                break;
            case "mile_end":
                 textNode = document.createTextNode("Mile End Road");
                 console.log(textNode);
                break;
            case "godward_square" :
                 textNode = document.createTextNode("Godward Square");
                break;
            case "computer_science":
                 textNode = document.createTextNode("CompSci Building");
                break;
            case "itl":
                 textNode = document.createTextNode("ITL Building");
                break;
            default: console.log("not fond");
    }
    text.appendChild(textNode);
    svg.appendChild(text);
}
```

debugging and outputting to console i see that the switch statement works fine, the problems is then in the last two lines of the function:

```
text.appendChild(textNode);
svg.appendChild(text);
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks :)

Comment: You don't actually state what goes wrong.  A demo snippet or fiddle would be useful.

Comment: BTW. The expression `(target.id=="svg_14"||"svg_16")` will always be true.  I think you meant `(target.id=="svg_14" || target.id=="svg_16")`

Comment: i get no errors nor nothing, but the code doesn't dowhat i would like to (show some text when the mouse is cliacked)

Comment: If you create a demo fiddle or snippet, we can have a look.  At the moment there is a bunch of missing code, so we couldn't be sure where the error is.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wn2nonff/ this is the fiddle. thanks

Comment: That fiddle has all sorts of problems.  You didn't fix the error I pointed out.  There are syntax errors (browser reports "Unexpected ';'".  You have extra and incomplete HTML tags (eg. "<canvas>"). And you are referencing functions that don't exist ("loadimage()" and "unloadimage()").  Why not simplify your sample down to a single road or building. Fix your obvious errors, then start from there.

Comment: Hint: if you haven't already, learn how to use the browsers dev console (press F12).  If you comment out your broken calls ("eg. loadimage()" and click on one of your rectangles, you get the error `Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="function toString() { [native code] }"`.  Look more closely at that line in your `showText()` function.